# determinstic trend in VAR-models

Tags: time-series, trend, vector-autoregression

I'm asking myself the following question. I want to build a VAR-Model with 6 time series A, B, C, D, E and F. I analysed every series univariate and I found out that A, D, E and F are stationary and B has a linear and C a quadratic deterministic trend. Analyzing the VAR seems like I need 2 Lags to include. Now I allow for estimating a linear trend for B and a quadratic trend for C in the VAR model, too - that makes sense for me. But I'm wondering if it is ok to build the following model (to allow only these specific trend terms for the associated variable, t-values are shown):
[image]

... or if I allow a quadratic trend for series C and since every series is effecting the other ones in a VAR-model do I then have to allow quadratic trends for ALL the other veriables, too? I think no, because if I would let the model estimate a deterministic trend for every series it will be significant for several series even if they don't have a quadratic (or linear) trend in fact.

Would be glad if someone can help me discussing this...

thanks, eski19

Comment: Some thoughts: suppose $y_t$ has no trend while $x_t$ has a linear trend. If I build a model where $y_t$ depends linearly on $x_t$ without any terms that would counterbalance the linear trend brought in by $x_t$, such a model would not make sense. $y_t$ and $x_t$ should diverge due to the linear trend in $x_t$. So even if $y_t$ itself does not have a linear trend, I would include a linear trend in the linear model in which $y_t$ depends on $x_t$ so as to counterbalance the effect of trend inside $x_t$. Alternatively, $x_t$ could be de-trended before entering the model.

Comment: That said, it is no surprise you would find the trend significant even in the equations where the dependent variable has no trend. It is because the trend counterbalances the effect of the trending regressors.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! So I would first find out the highest degree of deterministic trend (t, t², ...) for all the series I want to include in my VAR. E.g. if it is a cubic trend t³ then I allow t, t² and t³ in EVERY single equation of the VAR. If you detrend one series before entering the model you do not compare the original series any longer - the interpretation seems a little bit weired to me. It is the same if one series has a unit root and you difference only this series and put it in the VAR with the other original variables. Do I not compare apples and oranges then?

Comment: Sometimes de-trending can have a natural interpretation. You might be interested in how the fluctuations of $x_t$ around its trend affect $y_t$. Since the trend terms in the model equations will effectively de-trend $x_t$ anyway (since $y_t$ has no trend), this will be a nuisance. By looking at estimated equations, it might seem that there is some trend that $y_t$ is following, while actually the trend will be just counterbalancing the trend inside $x_t$. So using de-trended $x_t$ may in the end be more transparent and less deceptive when it comes to analyzing how $x_t$ affects $y_t$.

Comment: everything sounds reasonable, thanks! do you have a  bibliographical reference for citation where they recommend to detrend single variables before entering the model? In this case can I despite not comparing original variables go on with interpreting in this way that "if x changes like this then y changes like this" (and take the values from the VAR system)?

Comment: Umm, I do not remember any specific reference, but this is in line with the general methodology of separating `seasonal`, `trend` and `residual` components of time series. I guess some applied textbook might have something along these lines. No, you cannot say *if x changes like this then y changes like this*; but you can say *if x deviates from its linear trend like this then y changes like that*.

Comment: My problem is that I compare VAR-systems for 8 persons with the same variables in there. To have everything comparable (the variables from one person and the same variables between persons) I need to be able to say in the end "if x changes like this then y changes like this" and to compare the different strengths (for example if x effects y for two people it is interesting how differently strong the effect is). So in this case I have to go back to the alternative of entering the deterministic trends directly in the VAR-system, I think?... and should focus only on the matrix interpretions

Comment: Maybe the trends are very similar across persons. If so, you could still de-trend first. Or maybe the trend is a nuisance so that you know it is there but what is interesting are the deviations from it; that may often be quite plausible when the trend is deterministic rather than stochastic. It is up to you to decide this in the subject-matter context. I do not claim that de-trending outside the system is a better approach, it is more about easing the interpretation. So if you find de-trending to be difficult to interpret, then I guess you may as well keep the trend in the VAR model.

Comment: The trends are very different for one person - like in the example in my first post. Also the variables are psychological ones and so the trend itself is an important thing. So I think I go on with the trend in the model...

Comment: Just recall the main idea: when $y_t$ does not have a trend while $x_t$ does have a trend, a trend variable in the equation for $y_t$ should not be interpreted as the trend of $y_t$ but as a compensating factor for the trend inside $x_t$. Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22125/discussion-between-eski-and-richard-hardy).

Comment: @RichardHardy : unfortunately I have to reopen the question because I had the following impression:
the deterministic trends seem to be significant only for the equations where I would suppose deterministic trends and for the ones that are stationary when tested univariate but showed despite of this a little determinstic behaviour (that is often the case I think)... but for the series that look really completely stationary/white noise no det. trends are significant...

Comment: so... if I include a variable x with for example a quadratic trend as a predictor for a variable y that is stationary could it not be more reasonable that the estimated coefficient for x will be very small and not significant because it does not help to predict y? 
and so there is no deterministic trend as a counterpart? (we can chat, too)